# Laravel List by Date by Price, Price Desc

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have search result page for a car seller website, it a listing page. 
There are some options on html template like:

```
 order by data , price , price des
```

I should order results by clicking this options.
Client doesn't want to use datatables. How can I implement it? I know how to fetch data with laravel:

```
DB::table('<table name>')->orderBy('<field name>', '<direction>')->get();
```

But I couldn't understand the logic, because after I come to search result page with data, how can I take query and change the order at current page?

Or is there a technique for that?

Comment: Are you using laravel 4 or 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the column name and direction to the controller. And in the controller you get the column, direction and put them into orderBy function.

The link in your view should look something right this

http://www.yoururl.com/something?column=date&direction=asc

```
$sortable_fields = array("date", "price");

/* set the default the column sort field to date if there is no value was passed */  
$column = in_array(Input::get('column'), $searchable_fields) ? Input::get('column') : 'date'

/* set the default sort direction to desc if there is no value was passed */
$direction = (Input::get('direction') == 'asc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';



/* Use where function for searching before do the order by */
$query = DB::table('<table name>') ;
if (Input::get('title')) {
  $query->where('title', Input::get('title');
}
DB::table('<table name>')->orderBy($column, $direction)->get();
```

Comment: im not fetching all data from table , i fetch results according to search bar params. how will i take same params from search bar ?

Comment: nice code,  but my search page and results page are different. in search page there are lots of params , according to this params my controller fetch data , how will i take this params ands send it result page ?

Comment: @TolgaAteş You need to create new action in the controller. It might be `result()` . And the search from should point the that action.

Comment: can you describe more? i coulndt get the idea for this ?

Comment: What is your searching form look like now? Please show me your code.

Comment: my search form include about 15 inputs . some of them option ,some of them checkbox , some of them textbox . i m takin all of them and send them to controller from my search-page , and my controller fetch data according to this 15 input values and send results to a different page ( result-page ) , but on result page i have this :  order by date , price , price desc buttons

Comment: In result-page you need to pass all the search params that came from search page. And you need to put all the search params in the link and add the order column and direction into it (this link will point to result action itself). `xxx.xxx.com/result?title=title&column=date&direciton=desc`

Comment: Could you update the question with the code of result action?

Comment: i was doing search operation with post method , should i change it to get  ?

Comment: Yes, for searching it is better to use `get` because user might want to bookmark or copy the url for use it later.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to do the operation in datatables. Then you should do a ajax call to get that result in the any action such as on change or onpress event or anything that you required.

In laravel :

You need to make your `orderBy` such that

```
DB::table('users')->orderBy('name', 'desc')->get();
```

For more [info about selects](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)

Comment: How will i take same query from previous page ( search page ) , i have a big query from that page ?

Comment: Are you having the query in the view ?

Comment: You must have the query in the controller, then why can't you have the same query in both the functions ? and return it accordingly

Comment: i have just result in the view to list with `foreach`

Comment: should i make and send same query for different orders in same controller ?  i coulndt understand :(

Comment: Actually having the query inside the view in foreach is bad practise, no issue.. as you already have done it. What i am trying to say is, when the user clicks the `orderby` or any option in that page, you should call the ajax call using `onchange` event of those items, and in the `onchange` ajax call you should call the controller's function which will return the same query to your view

Comment: Actually you can `return` the table that you have in view from the another controller. So first time you will have a fresh table (result) , after the user click any action, you will have the view that is returned by the second controller. You got it ??

Comment: This query comes from search bar , How can i provide same inputs for this search bar ? it changes according to users choice...

Comment: You will send the user's choice along with the call, i.e., dropdown value or search text value or anything along in the ajax call. So then controller will return the table that you have in your view. And you will replace the old table with new one.

Comment: You mean , i will send this result to another controller ? and is it possible to  edit or order this result in another controller ?

Comment: but this search page in homepage and results in search-results page.first submit on search page is not a ajax request

Comment: You are not going to send the entire table to another controller, Just the user's choice i.e., `asc` or `desc` and some fields to the controller. So it is like the fresh operation in the another controller

Comment: Without seeing what you have in the first page and search-result page, it is hard to image . But the logic is you are sending the param to the controller and getting result accordingly

Comment: but i have lots of options in search bar , and my controller fetch datas according to this options. how ill another controller know this options, fetch data and order them ?

Comment: using form serialize you can have all the value in your view i.e., searchbar. So you are going to send all the datas that it was already choosed

Comment: my search form and results are not in same page :(